# How do I suppress RD confirmation

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a windows batch file which delete some directory inside windows home directory.

```
        REM clear Ivy cache on windows
        RD /s %UserProfile%\.grails\2.0.0\projects\core-accounting\plugins

        RD /s %UserProfile%\.grails\2.0.0\projects\core-domain-model\plugins
        RD /s %UserProfile%\.grails\2.0.0\projects\nemesis-base\plugins
        RD /s %UserProfile%\.grails\2.0.0\projects\nemesis-webapp\plugins

        RD /s %UserProfile%\.grails\ivy-cache\de.denkformat.grails.plugins\core-accounting
        RD /s %UserProfile%\.grails\ivy-cache\de.denkformat.grails.plugins\core-domain-model
```

But in this case, prompt always ask if I am going to really delete the directory.
Is there anyway to avoid the warning?

Comment: Jontatas' answer is what you need, however it may be worth noting that if you need help with CMD functions then you can ask it for help, e.g the command entered in this case is "RD /?" this will show you the /Q with an explanation as to what it does.

Answer (score 2):

/Q = Quiet mode, shouldn't ask if you really want to delete.

Answer (score 2):

As Jontatas said you can use:

`rd C:\folder /s /q`

Or you can use this neat trick to echo Y to the confirmation. You can also use this on commands that don't have a switch to suppress the confirmation for commands like `cacls`.

`echo y| rd C:\folder /s`